# Pandas series replace strings with numpy nan

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas series where data is of type `string`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['count']

0         4
1       nan
2       nan
3         1
4       nan
5       227.0
        ... 
635     nan
636     nan
637       1
638       8
639    None
```

I'd like to replace `nan` with `np.nan` and set the data type of numeric values to `int`

I tried this, but it didn't work. Values are still strings.

```
df['count'] = df['count'].apply(lambda x: np.where(x.isdigit(), x, np.nan))
```

Comment: `np.nan` is a float, so the column dtype will still be `object`.

Comment: why not replace anything that doesn't convert to numeric with `np.nan`? And keep the type as float, following @hpaulj's comment.

Comment: `np.where(cond, A, B)` evaluates all of `A` and `B`.  It selects between the two, but it is NOT an conditional evaluator.  In other words if is not `if cond do A else do B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is:

```py
df['count'] = pd.to_numeric(df['count'], errors='coerce')
```

After that, your column will be `np.float64` and anything that could not be converted to a float will be `np.nan`.

A common way to convert such a column to `int` is to chose a value to replace 'nan'. That is application-dependent, of course, but since your column name is 'count', a value of -1 could perhaps be adequate.

Alternatively, you can use pandas' [nullable integer](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html).

### Example

```py
df = pd.DataFrame('4 nan nan 1 nan 227.0 1 8 None'.split(), columns=['count'])

>>> df
   count
0      4
1    nan
2    nan
3      1
4    nan
5  227.0
6      1
7      8
8   None
```

Method 1: convert to numeric, then to int with -1 to indicate "bad value":

```py
newdf = df.assign(
    count=pd.to_numeric(df['count'], errors='coerce')
    .fillna(-1)
    .astype(int)
)

>>> newdf
   count
0      4
1     -1
2     -1
3      1
4     -1
5    227
6      1
7      8
8     -1
```

Method 2: convert to 'Int64' (nullable integer):

```py
newdf = df.assign(
    count=pd.to_numeric(df['count'], errors='coerce')
    .astype('Int64')
)

>>> newdf
   count
0      4
1   <NA>
2   <NA>
3      1
4   <NA>
5    227
6      1
7      8
8   <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a list comprehension for this:

```
df['count'] = [int(val) if val != "nan" else np.nan for val in df['count']]
```

If the casting doesn't work (i.e. you have other numerics that are not `int`), you can try casting as a float as a catch all and then convert to an int: `int(float(val))`

```
df['count'] = [int(float(val)) if val != "nan" else np.nan for val in df['count']]
```

Alternatively, if you wish to be more *pandthonic*, you can try to use one of these [approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas/28648923#28648923) (specifically, [`to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)).

Comment: This is actually a list comprehension, not just for loop

Comment: @KevinM Found a case where this fails: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '227.0'. I modified the question.

Comment: Changed response accordingly. I still recommend using a list comprehension, as it's stricter, but Pandas' `to_numeric` is also an option.

Comment: For example, your value of `None` will cause the list comprehension to error but not with `to_numeric()`/Pierre D's response. Your *question* is asking about *nans*. Is `None` suppose to be taken up like nan or is it an inherit issue with your dataset? You could potentially be ignoring problems in your dataset by using `to_numeric()` blindly when the latter is the case.